# NSDateFormatter timeIntervalSince1970 strange behavior with milliseconds

Tags: nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse a date with milliseconds using `NSDateFormatter`, and I'm getting weird results when I print out its time interval since 1970. Here's my test code:

```
var timeStr = "2015-09-29 14:32:42.297-07"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSx"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeStr)!
let dateFormatted = String(format: "%.20f", date.timeIntervalSince1970)
print("date: \(dateFormatted)")
```

Result: `"date: 1443562362.29699993133544921875\n"`

Instead of ending with 297, it ends with something close to it. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is just how doubles work. It's not related to `NSDateFormatter`. If I make a double with value 2.3 then print it to 20 decimal places, I get 2.99999990453636... or something.

Comment: It's how floating point numbers work on computers in general.